# Cutting down on memory use in recursive algorithm by mapping String to int

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote a program in Java that recursively performs path traversal and carries the path thus far, each step in the path is a String and therefor I was thinking initially that to cut down on memory use of the algorithm it could be better to map the Strings that represent each place on the map by with an int and carry it instead of the String.

However when I thought a bit more I wasn't sure anymore since what's being carried is the reference not the actual String(I always pass the reference), so would mapping the String values to ints:

1) would only increase the memory used overall by introducing an additional int array?

2) would decrease the memory used when the recursive method is handling the current int array instead of a String array?

I definitely would like to read up more on recursive algorithms and there issues implementations in Java, if anyone has any good links.

Comment: too general... I don't understand: what is you question?! Strings - yes, use them. Integers - yes, would be faster in many cases. BUT What are you doing - is NOT clear anyway(((

Comment: Avoid using more additional Strings to avoid adding strings to the string pool.  You could also use StringBuffer or StringBuilder in order to avoid adding Strings to the string pool.  StringBuffer objects and StringBuilder objects can be GC'd as well and will not reside in the String pool.  And as @SergeBreusov stated, being more specific might help some. :)

Comment: I don't understand how any of this can be too general, rather than the opposite just as general as it should be??? A step is represented by a String, should I map Strings to ints and then carry the ints. There is a weird arrogance about SO that makes no sense

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Given the info we have so far I'd say you will only use more memory if you introduce your Map idea. You only pass references to the recursive methods and it costs the same regardless of type.

But if you provide some sample code we might be able to give you a better answer. Sample code is generally a key success factor if you want good answers here on SO.